# Why isn't my PN2222A Transistor Working as Expected?

Tags: transistors, bjt

At the moment I am trying to learn how transistors work, so I set up a simple circuit to test my knowledge using a PN2222A transistor.

[image: Circuit]

3 V is from a battery pack containing two AA batteries. 6.6 V is from a somewhat depleted 9 V battery (8.3 V open circuit) that is experiencing a bit of voltage sag when connected to the rest of the circuit.

Here is what I expect:

The base current should be I<sub>b</sub> = (3 V - 0.6 V)/220Ω = 0.0109 A. I have confirmed this in practice with a multimeter by measuring 2.35 V across the 220 Ω resistor.

As per the [datasheet](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/Datasheets/PN2222-D.pdf), the DC current gain is at least 35, so the transistor should pass I<sub>c,allow</sub> = 35 * 0.0109 A = 0.382 A. The battery is able to supply 6.6 V / 50 Ω = 0.132 A. This is less than I<sub>c,allow</sub> so no problem. In practice, however, I measure the voltage across the 50 Ω resistor to be 1.5 V, so I<sub>c</sub> = 1.5 V / 50 Ω = 0.03 A.

So, I appear to be getting a DC current gain of h<sub>FE</sub> = 0.03 A / 0.0109 A = 2.8 which makes no sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your pinout is wrong. Check again. Left to right EBC

Comment: Then understand why hFE reduces when Vcb conducts as it becomes positive.

Comment: Are you using a breadboard for this? Or you soldered your circuit?

Comment: I think Tony is right, ngatesh. A reverse beta might very well be around 3 or so. There are only six permutations of the BJT in this circuit and just one of them is correct. That makes for 5 possible incorrect ways. But if you got the base right, then it is a 50/50 toss up and the wrong one there might show beta approx 3.

Comment: Simply , it is backwards. Murphy's Law strikes again.

Comment: We'll, that's embarrassing... I just rebuilt the circuit because I couldn't remember how I had it before, and now the results make sense, so it probably was backwards. Thanks guys. Tony Steward EE75, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it since you got here first.

Comment: @ngatesh You can write your own answer, too. Since you know more about it, too, that would make it a fairly complete and accurate answer. Then you can select it or select someone else's, as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

After rebuilding the circuit, the transistor behaved as expected. **Most likely I had the collector/emitter reversed**. Since the transistor was technically "working" I didn't think to check this, but now I know that it will still function backwards at low gain.

Thanks Tony Stewart EE75, jonk, and gbarry for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat-depleted 6.6 volt battery may no longer be at 6.6 volts.  Check it with the circuit running.  It may be closer to 2 volts.

If there's 1.5 volts across the resistor, that means there's 5.1 volts across the transistor, which would be either a bad transistor or a circuit error.  The transistor should be saturated, with 0.3v or less from collector to emitter.

Comment: By the way, are you certain of the pinout? You can swap C and E without hurting the transistor.  When you have them swapped, the transistor still works, but with low gain.

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation, you suppose your transistor is polarized in a way it is in it's linear zone. That's not the case. In fact, it is saturated.

Why is it saturated? Your calculation is right : in linear zone, your current collector should be 0.382A but then, the voltage across the 50 ohms resistor would be 19,1V. To reach such a collector current, your 6,6V supply voltage should in fact be at least higher than 19,1V + the PN2222A parameter called Vcesat (approximately 0,2V).

But be careful if you increase your supply voltage! With such a current flowing in it, your 50 ohms resistor must dissipate 0.382x0.382x50=7.3W!
I suggest you to increase the 220 ohms resistor to 1k. The voltage across the 50 ohms resistor will then be approximately 4V and a 6.6V supply voltage will be enough. And less current drained from the depleted 9V battery will help it maintain a sufficient voltage for your circuit to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to supply 1/3 of an amp from a dead 9V battery will lead to sketchy results. That's why you are getting non sensible measurements